# Json.net deserialization issue when target is an abstract object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I'm using a service which returns a `json`.

I have a key-value object where the key is a `string` and the value is an `object`and I know where to cast the object based on the key.

It will look something like:

```
{
  "key1": "This is key 1",
  "key2": 12,
  "key3": ["Key 3 first item", "Key 3 second item"]
}
```

With simple types (e.g.) `strings`, `long`, `int` etc. There is no problem.
 My problem starts when I receive an `array` (key3).

My c# code will look something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, object> values = GetValuesFromTheService();
string str = (string)values["key1"]; // Ok
long lng = (long)values["key2"]; // Ok
List<string> strs = (List<string>)values["key3"]; // BAD
```

key3 is actually a `JArray` and not a `List<string>` - I guess this happens since I'm using an `object` as a value and not being more specific (a `List<object>` will also be better then a `JArray`).

Is there anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar situation when attempting to (de)serialize some of our custom enumerations. For the solution, I created a custom JsonConvertor. Here's the code I use for that...

```
public class EnumerationConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var enm = (Enumeration)value;
            writer.WriteValue(enm.Value);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.Value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            int value;

            if (reader.ValueType == typeof(Int64))
            {
                value = Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                value = (int)reader.Value;
            }

            return Enumeration.FromValueOrDefault(objectType, value);

        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            if (objectType.BaseType == null) return false;
            return objectType.BaseType.Name == "Enumeration";
        }
    }
```

Then, when I want to invoke it and pull the json back into my object, here's the line for that one...

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CustomObjectDto>>(req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, new EnumerationConverter());
```

Nice thing is that this becomes universally available and the CustomObjectDto can just have an instance of this magic dictionary in it as a property...or even multiple...and will apply the conversion on only the properties that match according to the logic in the convertor...hope that helps.

And here's a link to a similar topic --> http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to parse the entire object to a jObject and then select the keys back out to the types you need. This is untested but the basic idea.

```
var j = JObject.Parse(GetValuesFromTheService());
string str = (string)j.SelectToken("key1");
long lng = (long)j.SelectToken("key2");
var strs = (List<string>)j.SelectToken("key3");
```

Comment: This doesn't compile and isn't really what I'm looking for. I can think about a couple of work arounds that will work - I'm looking for a smarter way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If `key3` is a `JArray` of `string` values, you can do the following:

```
List<string> strs = ((JArray)values["key3"]).Select(t => t.Value<string>()).ToList();
```

Comment: I know how to Covert a JArray to a List -> I want the Deserialization to handle this behind the scenes somehow.

Comment: You shouldn't deserialize everything into a `Dictionary<string, object>` then. Try to create a C# class that models your JSON and then use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(jsonString)` ([Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json))

Comment: I know that it's a bad practice to create an abstract Dictionary, but I'm using an external source and that's the output.
I can't create a class that will support this situation.